# get image button by tag id

Tags: java, android

I have image button with different tag ids.

```
ImageButton mFavorite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.method_fav_btn);
mFavorite.setTag(pm.getId());
```

On click I want to identify which image button was clicked. and on the basis of that i want to change it's image.

```
mFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Change images:
        mFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
    }
});
```

But, it's not changing. How can I identify button by it's tag id?

Comment: You don't seem to be using tags at all (only set them). And what's `pm`  anyway?

Comment: It's object. from that I am setting up the value of tag.

Comment: @user3249477: Is there any way to change image of the selected button?

Comment: Why not use `view.getTag()` inside your `onClick` method?

Comment: @RonakPatel I don't really understand the purpose of using `setTag(..)` method. Do you register button objects to only one  click listener? If so, `view.getTag()` will solve your problem. In fact, `view` represents button object.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Activity` implement `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class example extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public example() {
        ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(this);
        ImageButton b2 = new ImageButton(this);
        ImageButton b3 = new ImageButton(this);

        b1.setTag("b1");
        b2.setTag("b2");
        b3.setTag("b3");

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String tag = String.valueOf(view.getTag());

        if (tag == "b1") {
            // B1 was clicked
        } else if (tag == "b2") {
            // b2 was clicked
        } else if (tag == "b3") {
            // b3 was clicked
        }
    }
}
```